# How can I fix '[vuex] unknown action type: lookupName' within my Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, action, vuex

I am having an issue calling up an action from my Vue component using this.$store.dispatch('lookupName'). I have tried console logging the this.$store method, but the actions within it are empty.

Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'  
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { findCertificate } from '@/api';

Vue.use(Vuex)


const state = {  
  // single source of data
  nameLookup: {},

}

const actions = {  
  // asynchronous operations
  lookupName(context, form){
    return findCertificate(form)
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({  
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
})

export default store
```

Vue Component

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
import { mapGetters,  mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
    created() {

    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            lookupName: 'lookupName'
        }),
        ...mapActions({
            add: 'lookupName'
        }),
        onCaptchaVerified: function(recaptchaToken){
            this.$refs.recaptcha.reset();
            console.log(this.$store.dispatch('lookupName', this.form))

        },
    }
}
```

Why am I still getting this error? I have looked up many other people's questions about similar issues, but those solutions did not work for me.

Comment: Do you still get the error? I can't reproduce it here.

Comment: Try to mapAction just once using `,` and then call `this.lookupName()` (you can do this because you've just mapped using mapActions)

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your feedback. The issue was that the default store.js that had been added was being called instead of the new /store/index.js that I had created to keep it more organized. I removed the folder and copied my index.js file into store.js and that fixed it. Thanks again.